# When I link react-native-video show me a error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-video

When I link `react-native-video` show me a error

[image: image error]

Answer (score 0):

cd android && ./gradlew clean 
and test again

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like an executed `link` command but like you try to build an APK and run it.
So be aware, that you remove the previous installed APK from your device before you bundle an new one.

Comment: This just happens when I linked the react-native-video, when I just install and don't link work without problems, but I need link